# Can't ping websites with domains but can ping websites with ips

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dns, webmin

The DNS on my Ubuntu Server isn't working. I changed some settings while trying to get my domain to go to my server and I think I reverted the changed back but it still doesn't work. It started happening after I removed Webmin by doing:

```
apt remove webmin
```

I know the problem is with dns since:

Pinging Google.com:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9Uto.png

Pinging 142.250.64.238 (Google's ip)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCcOo.png

Also I now can't update my server since the packages use domains:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/89grR.png

This is what shows up when I do the command ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:8c:fd:4a:1b:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.13/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 83038sec preferred_lft 83038sec
    inet6 2600:8802:2901:8a00:a28c:fdff:fe4a:1b0e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86384sec preferred_lft 86384sec
    inet6 fe80::a28c:fdff:fe4a:1b0e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 68:14:01:51:32:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Is this Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop? Which version? Have you checked to see if DNS servers are defined for the network? `sudo ip a` should provide this info.

Comment: It's Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 and when I do sudo ip a it says **unable to resolve host server.bettermc.online: Name or service not known** (Which is the domain I was trying to set up). It also shows the network info for  enp1s0, lo wlo1

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `ip a`? This may make it easier for people to provide specific solutions. 

Answer (score -1):

try this flow:

remove the symlink:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

in **/etc/resolv.conf**

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

put

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and make it immutable:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

> The last command will add immutable bit, so the file doesn't get
> overwritten. After you set immutable bit, even the root account will
> not be able to write to the file. If you wish to edit the file again
> latter on, and remove immutable bit, use this command:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

[No write permissions on a file even with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947574/no-write-permissions-on-a-file-even-with-sudo)

Comment: You shouldn't do this unless you know what you're doing.  This will break SystemD's resolve system, which is the new system in 18.04+ for local system resolution.