# DNS configuration is reset by a network manager

Tags: network-manager, dns, syslinux

On one of the server the dns configuration in the `/etc/resolv.conf` gets changed by the network manager of daemon. Does anybody know the solution and why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Simply set the required DNS nameservers in Network Manager: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cumpo.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dhcp client, then every time you acquire new IP from the DHCP server, Network Manger will update /etc/resolv.conf with DNS from the server.
You an avoid this by editing config file in

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethXXX
```

where ethXXX is the name of your network device
you can manually add DNS of you liking like this

```
DNS1=1.2.3.4
DNS2=1.2.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf              #remove the symlink
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf            #create the new file and populate it as you wish
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf       #change its attribute
```

> The last command will add immutable bit, so the file doesn't get overwritten. After you set immutable bit, even the root account will not be able to write to the file. If you wish to edit the file again latter on, and remove immutable bit, use this command:

`sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf`

[No write permissions on a file even with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947574/no-write-permissions-on-a-file-even-with-sudo)